# Rewriting the nth term of a series in the form $ar^{n-1}$

Tags: geometric-series

In the formula below, where does the $\frac{4}{3}$ come from and what happened to the $3$? How did they get the far right answer? Taken from Stewart Early Transcendentals Calculus textbook.

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1} 2^{2n}3^{1-n}=\sum^\infty_{n=1}(2^2)^{n}3^{-(n-1)}=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{4^n}{3^{n-1}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty4\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{n-1}$$

Comment: By using $A^{BC} = (A^B)^C$ and $A^{-B} = 1/A^B$ and $4^n = 4\cdot 4^{n-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{4^n}{3^{n-1}}=\frac{4^{1+(n-1)}}{3^{n-1}}$$

$$=\frac{4^1\cdot 4^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}$$

$$=4\cdot \frac{4^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}$$

$$=4\cdot\big(\frac{4}{3}\big)^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{4^n}{3^{n-1}}=\frac{4^1\cdot 4^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}=4\cdot\frac {4^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}=4\cdot\left(\frac43\right)^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
2^{2n}3^{1-n} = (2^2)^n3^{-(n-1)} = 4^n3^{-(n-1)} = \frac{4^n}{3^{n-1}} = \frac{4\cdot4^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}} = 4\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{n-1}
$$
Here we have used the formulas

1. $$
   a^ma^k = a^{m+k}
   $$
2. $$
   a^{-m} = \frac{1}{a^m}
   $$
3. $$
   (a^m)^k = a^{mk}
   $$
4. $$
   \frac{a^m}{b^m} = \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{m}
   $$
   So

> In the formula below, where does the $\frac{4}{3}$ come from

It came from moving the exponent outside using formula 4 above.

> and what happened to the 3?

Nothing happened to the $3$.

> How did they get the far right answer?

The last step is using the formula 4 from above.